# Windows 7 "missing operating system" on boot

Tags: windows-7, boot

I've had a weird problem lately when booting Windows 7 Ultimate:

1. If I restart the PC, Windows 7 boots as usual.
2. If I shut the PC down and start it up I get a "Missing operating system" error. If I then restart with Windows 7 installation disk and quit the installation with "Restart", Windows boots normally. The same applies with the Ubuntu 11 installation disk.

I've noticed that this is my disk set up:

[image]

On my other PC the "Unallocated" partition is called "System Reserved" with a status of (Active, System). Could that be related to this problem?

I've tried System Repair with <kbd>F8</kbd> but this didn't change anything. I've had the PC for over a year now and this problem only started around a week ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird. Maybe you can use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) to fix things up? I find EasyBCD painfully delightful to use.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on how to use EasyBCD in my case?

Comment: Sure, you get your Windows instance booted, doing whatever you've been doing. You install EasyBCD, then have it install to your MBR. Make sure that its boot menu is configured to include your windows installation.. While you're editing that boot menu, install that bios extender thing, that's kind handy. Reboot and you'll presumably have a workable boot menu - go back and edit to your delight.

Comment: Holly cr@p! You genius, you! This definitely resolved my problem. I also need to note that I changed the BIOS settings to Safe Defaults. The weird disk allocation issue is still there, but I as long as the OS loads normally, I'm happy. Thanks, man.

Comment: @Daniel - You're welcome dude. I'm not that genius, the freaks that figured that program out, they're the real heros. I quite like Grub, I use it more than anything, but I gotta admit, EasyBCD is a lot easier for me to use and seems similarly feature rich. Glad you're back on track. Grats!